# Dynamic LinearLayout in ListView Item

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm using a ListView with a custom adapter that gets a JSONArray (from a Facebook request). Each ListView item has two TextViews and one or two ImageViews depending on the post type. Each list item also has a LinearLayout that I'm calling the "comments box".

When I define the list item in the xml, the comments box contains only a TextView for the title ("Comments and Likes"). In the custom adapter, parse the comments data (correctly I hope), and add TextViews programatically for each comment so I don't create and inflate empty TextViews for nothing.

The problem I'm having, which seems like a common ListView recycling problem, is that the comments box doesn't retain its contents when scrolling through the list. I looked through the JSON data and every object in the array has the same fields for "comments", so I wouldn't think that I'm getting null for anything in the data, especially if all the other data loads and populates perfectly fine. I can't tell what I'm doing wrong since everything else works but this. Here is the getView() method of my adapter.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;

    try {
        jsonObject = getItem(position);
        jsonFrom = jsonObject.getJSONObject("from");
        postType = jsonObject.getString("type");
        posterName = jsonFrom.getString("name");
        posterID = jsonFrom.getString("id");
        posterPhoto = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + posterID + "/picture?type=square";
        if (jsonObject.has("name")) {
            posterMessage = jsonObject.getString("name");
        }
        else if (jsonObject.has("story")){
            posterMessage = jsonObject.getString("story");
        }
        else if (jsonObject.has("message")){
            posterMessage = jsonObject.getString("message");
        }
        else{
            posterMessage = "No message.";
        }
        if(jsonObject.has("picture")){
            posterImageURL = jsonObject.getString("picture");
        }
        commentsData = jsonObject.getJSONObject("comments");
        commentsCount = commentsData.getInt("count");


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_holder,null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.posterName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.posterName);
        holder.posterMessage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.posterMessage);
        holder.posterProfilePhoto = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.posterProfilePic);
        holder.posterImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.posterImage);
        holder.commentsBox = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentsBox);
        if(postType.equals("photo")){
            holder.posterImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if(commentsCount!=0 && commentsCount!=null){
            try {
                commentsArray = commentsData.getJSONArray("data");
                for(int index = 0; index<commentsArray.length(); index++){
                    comment = commentsArray.getJSONObject(index);
                    commenterName = comment.getJSONObject("from").getString("name");
                    commenterId = comment.getJSONObject("from").getString("id");
                    commentMessage = comment.getString("message");
                    TextView commentMessageHolder = new TextView(activity);
                    commentMessageHolder.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>"+commenterName+"</b>"+"  "+commentMessage));
                    holder.commentsBox.addView(commentMessageHolder, index+1);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } 
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        if(postType.equals("photo")){
            holder.posterImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            holder.posterImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    if (jsonObject != null) {
        holder.posterName.setText(posterName);
        if (posterMessage != null) {
            holder.posterMessage.setText(posterMessage);
        } else {
            holder.posterMessage.setText("No message for this post.");
        }

        imageLoader.displayImage(posterPhoto,holder.posterProfilePhoto);

        if(postType.equals("photo")){
            if(posterImageURL != null){
                holder.posterImage.setTag(posterImageURL);
                imageLoader.displayImage(posterImageURL, holder.posterImage);
            }
        }
    }

    return convertView;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem I'm having, which seems like a common ListView recycling
>   problem, is that the comments box doesn't retain its contents when
>   scrolling through the list.

The main problem is that you build the comments `TextViews` **only** for the case when `convertView` is `null`, when the user will scroll the `ListView` you'll end up with those initially set rows views(with comments) that you don't modify for unwanted positions. Move the comments `for` loop outside of the if clause where you check `convertView` for `null`.

Also, you may want to cache that json parsing, not to mention that you need to take in consideration to not over add comments `TextViews` as the recycled row view could already have its' own comment `TextViews`.

Comment: That was it. Thanks a lot! I'm pretty new at Android programming, so what process would be used to cache the json parsing? Thanks.

Comment: You could have a list(with the size of the data) of a custom object which will hold all of the data values from the json structure corresponding to a row. In the `getView` method you'll check this list to see if you have something stored for that row. If you don't(when you first get to that position) then do the current extraction and put the data in the list. The next time you'll get to that row you'll already parsed the json structure and you simply retrieve the data from the list.